# Использовать SIMD инструкцию через сложную структуру на языке СИ

Tags: c, ассемблер, структуры, arm, stm32

Есть SIMD инструкция выполняющая следующую операцию:

```
res[7:0]   = val1[7:0]   - val2[7:0]   >> 1
res[15:8]  = val1[15:8]  - val2[15:8]  >> 1
res[23:16] = val1[23:16] - val2[23:16] >> 1
res[31:24] = val1[31:24] - val2[31:24] >> 1
```

Хочется выполнить эту операцию над четными и не четными элементами массива, т.е.

```
res = __SHSUB8(четные, нечетные);
```

**Но не выполнять операцию разделения массива вручную**

Пример для понимания (**Код не правильный**):

```
struct {
    uint8_t x1;
    uint8_t x2;
    uint8_t x3;
    uint8_t x4;
    uint8_t x5;
    uint8_t x6;
    uint8_t x7;
    uint8_t x8;
    uint8_t arr1[4] = {x1,x3,x5,x7};
    uint8_t arr2[4] = {x2,x4,x6,x8};
} test;
res = __SHSUB8(test.arr1, test.arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

В две инструкции - никак. Нет нужных инструкций перемешивания данных. Всё, чем Вы располагаете, описано в **ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual**. Вам же нужно [Rearranging Vectors](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/coding-for-neon---part-5-rearranging-vectors). Может быть вопрос отпадёт, ели пересмотреть способ решения этой задачи или задачи уровнем выше?